# Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "hello-node-64c578bdf8-jp7dt" not found

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to expose my pod

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node-64c578bdf8-jp7dt --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "hello-node-64c578bdf8-jp7dt" not found
```

These are my pods

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hazelcast-76c4785db6-wnzsb        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          120m
hello-minikube-7bdc84f4b7-qfjv9   1/1     Running            0          113m
hello-node-64c578bdf8-jp7dt       1/1     Running            0          114m
```

My kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", GitCommit:"c27b913fddd1a6c480c229191a087698aa92f0b1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:37:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", GitCommit:"c27b913fddd1a6c480c229191a087698aa92f0b1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:30:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

What are these deployment extensions?

```
kubectl get deployments
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hazelcast        0/1     1            0           139m
hello-minikube   1/1     1            1           132m
hello-node       1/1     1            1           133m
```

Comment: paste the output of kubectl get deployments, maybe you are trying to expose a pod instead of deployment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the deployment using:

```
kubectl get deployments
```

then use  that name in expose command. maybe you are trying to expose the pod name

So the correct command is:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the deployment using :

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
app           hello-node       1/1     1            1           22m
```

then use that name in expose command. maybe you are trying to expose the pod name

So the correct command is:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 -n app
```